# Alchemy 0.8.2 Uninstaller throwing an error 1001

Tags: a4t

Recently when trying to uninstall Alchemy4Tridion 0.8.2 from the Control Panel Programs and Features, I got the following error 1001 and not able to uninstall Alchemy4Tridion installer:

[image]

(An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete. --> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

I've also tried to run the repair tool and received the same the error 1001 message (like the picture above).

I am not able to install another Alchemy installer, repair or uninstall the current installer. Alchemy4Tridion just remains in the Programs and Features.

According the help article on how to Uninstall Alchemy http://www.alchemywebstore.com/help/how-to/Video-Uninstall-Alchemy, users should be able to uninstall the Alchemy4Tridion from the Control Panel Programs and Features.

Can anyone, who experienced the similar issue please explain to me:

- Why am I getting this error?
- How can I resolve this error to use Alchemy in Tridion?

Answer (score 5):

Some users will receive this error when trying to uninstall the Alchemy 0.8.1 and 0.8.2 Alchemy4Tridion Installer. This is because the Alchemy Windows Service is running.

The Alchemy Window Service was added to the 0.8.1 and 0.8.2 Alchemy4Tridion Installer. Some Tridion environments may block

To resolve this issue you must:

1. **Run** the command `sc delete AlchemyService` (which removes the Alchemy Windows Service)
2. **Repair** the current Alchemy4Tridion installer from the Control Panel Program and Features
3. **Uninstall** the Alchemy4Tridion installer

Comment: I dont think you need to run repair current Alchemy installation. Only first step is crucial for to be able to be uninstalled.